# Nuclear fission difference in energy calculation?

Tags: electrostatics, nuclear-physics

If you have a uranium atom of radius $10^{-14}m$ that undergoes fission into two fragments each with 46 protons and radius $8\times10^{-15}m$. There are two ways you can calculate the electrostatic energy realised (according to my textbook):

1. Find the electric potential energy of the two fragments as if they where point charges at a distance of $2\times8\times10^{-15}m$ apart (i.e. find the potential energy one of these charges would have in the field of the other). This gives an answer of around 180 MeV.
2. Find the electrostatic energy of the original nucleus by imagining the nucleus was built layer by layer each of thickness $dr$ and then integrating over it to find the energy of the whole nucleus. If this is then repeated for the two fragments and the sum of the electrostatic energies of the fragments is taken from that of the original nucleus that is the electrostatic energy released. But this gives an energy of around 270MeV.

Here is my question, why is there a difference between these two values (the 180MeV and the 270MeV)?

Comment: Did you expect them to be the same? The geometry is different, with the two fragment case more spread out (overall) than the large-nucleus case.

Comment: @dmckee I think you may have misunderstood my question I am wanting to know why there is a difference between the 180MeV value and the 270MeV value. If you have not please could you explain on your comment in a bit more detail, thanks.

Comment: @Joseph: because you're calculating the energy of two completely different geometries, so of course you get two different answers. Why would you expect two 8fm spheres to have the same energy as a single 10fm sphere?

Comment: @JohnRennie I understand this but this is not what my question was ment to be about. It is saying if you find the potential energy released by the first method (i.e. 1) it is not the same as if you find it with the second method (i.e. 2)

Comment: You aren't calculating the PE released. You're calculating the PE relative to the charges dispersed to infinity. The difference between your two PEs, 180 - 270MeV, is the energy needed to separate your single sphere into the two spheres.

Comment: @JohnRennie the difference when the two spheres are right next to each other and have not flown apart??

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The next questions is "What's happened to the difference in the two-small nuclei configuration?", and the answer is those two bits are in motion.